# How to use Django Template to get attributes of html tags

Tags: python, django

So I have a webpage with a radio button on it. So when the default option is selected, Django displays English units. When the other option is selected, Django displays Metric units.

**index.html**

```
<form>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input id="English" type="radio" name="optradio" checked="checked"> <p>English</p>
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input id="Metric" type="radio" name="optradio"><p>Metric</p>
    </label>
</form>

{% if getByID("English").checked="checked" %}
    {% for length, width in english %}
        <p>{{ length }} Miles X {{ width }} Miles</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    {% for length, width in metric %}
        <p>{{ length }} Kilometers X {{ width }} Kilometers</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

I've been searching for hours, but haven't found anyone using template language to base conditions off of other elements. 
Would anyone know how to properly do this?

Comment: Try doing it through javascript/jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

So you wont be able to do this with a Django template. This is because the template is rendered once by the server when a user requests the page (or it may use a cached version if you have that enabled). This means that it will not update when you select a different radio button.

For that you will want to use javascript. A DOM manipulation library like jQuery will make this easier.

For example you could render your template like this

```
{% for length, width in metric %}
    <p><span class="value" kilometres={{ length }}>{{ length }}</span>
    Kilometers X
    <span class="value" kilometres={{ width }}>{{ width }}</span>
    Kilometers</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Then in javascript you could update the spans based on what radio button is checked and their kilometres attribute. If you were using jQuery it could be done like this:

```
   $('#English').change(function() {
       if ($(this).checked) {
           $('.value').each(function() {
               var kilo = $(this).attr('kilometres');
               var miles = kilo * 0.621371;
               $(this).html(miles);
           })
       }
   })
```

You would also have to add some code for the other radio button